# Comparing different array indexes Javascript

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to run an if loop to compary if the value of timesheets at [i] index is equal to the value of timesheets at [i +1] index. But the value of timesheets [i + 1] is always returning as undefined

```
<% for(i=0; i < timesheets.length; i++){ %>
            <td><%= timesheets[i][5] %></td>
            <% if(timesheets[i][0] != timesheets[i + 1][0]){ %>
                <% for(a=0; timesheets[a] == timesheets[i]; a++){ %>
                    <% timesheets.splice[a]; %>
                <% } %>
<%}%><%}%>
```

Error Log:

```
TypeError: D:\reports\displayTimesheets.ejs:13
    11|         <% for(i=0; i < timesheets.length; i++){ %>
    12|             <td><%= timesheets[i][5] %></td>
 >> 13|             <% if(timesheets[i][0] != timesheets[i + 1][0]){ %>
    14|                 <% for(a=0; timesheets[a] == timesheets[i]; a++){ %>
    15|                     <% timesheets.splice[a]; %>
    16|                 <% } %>

Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

Comment: `timesheets[i + 1]` will overflow because you're checking for `i < timesheets.length` -- you could do `for (i=0; i < timesheets.length - 1; i++) {}`

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably happening on the last go around of your loop, when it's reached the full length of the array. At that point, there is no i+1 because it's the end of the array.

You will have to check for whether you are the end or not

try `if(timesheets[i+1] && timesheets[i][0] !== timesheets[i+1][0])`

This will check if the object even exists before attempting to access a property on the null timesheet.

Hope this helps!